# Unable to get longitude and latitude kotlin android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, latitude-longitude

Here's my code:

```
    private var longitude = ""
    private var latitude = ""
```

In the oncreateView, I have to do a api call with my latitude and longitude data. But the value of latitude and longitude never change!

```
//location
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
//        getCurrentLocation

        checkPermissions()

        //CALL API
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(" API_PATH?latitude=$latitude&longitude=$longitude")
            .build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
...
```

```
private fun checkPermissions(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), 1)
        }
        else{
            getLocations()
        }
    }

    private fun getLocations() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it == null){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "sorry can't get the location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else it.apply {
                latitude = it.result.latitude.toString()
                longitude = it.result.longitude.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if(requestCode== 1){
            if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //permission granted
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        getLocations()
                    }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //denied permission
            }
        }
    }
```

First, I enter always in th first condition in checkPermissions(). I don't know why. Secondly, I also try to write getLocations() in the first condition in the first if in checkPermissions(). But longitude and latitude are never update.
Can you help me please, I am on this case for a long time and I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you always enter the first condition in checkPermissions() because you haven't yet granted the permissions.
2. I think you need to request the permissions where the TODO code is commented out.

It will be something like:

```
// You can directly ask for the permission.
requestPermissions(CONTEXT,
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION),
        REQUEST_CODE)
```

Found from https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

I hope that steers you in the right direction.

If you want to cheat for testing, you can go to Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions and enable the permissions and then re-test. Of course, you'll have to do the request in code for the users of your app before you release the app.

Comment: When I add a call of getLocations after calling checkPermissions in my code, it doesn't enter in the if in getLocation while entering the getLocation call. Also, it doesn't enter in the fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener so it's not setting the longitude and latitude. My goal here is that I want that the variables longitude and latitude are changed with the right values.  
So if it doesn't enter the «if» in getLocations, it's because I have the permission. So why it is not entering the fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListene?